# Sending JSON to WebSocket in C# double-quotes

Tags: c#, json, websocket

I am having a hard time sending well formatted JSON (an object converted by NewtonSoft JsonConvert) to a websocket in C#.

```
string msg = "{\"test\" : 123}";
var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg);
var segment = new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer);
await this._socket.SendAsync(segment, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, this._cancel.Token);
```

Whenever I send any double quotes to my NodeJS server it returns a 500 server error so I am guessing that it's not being escaped properly when it's being converted to UTF8.

Any ideas?

Comment: try replacing double quotes with single quote.

Comment: But JSON is defined as "a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in double quotes".

Comment: single-quote is also valid and can replace the double-quote.

Comment: @ZCT No it's not. *Strings* in JSON are defined as characters inside double quotes. Which you already did. That `msg` is a valid JSON string - an object with a property `test` and value `123`

Comment: 500 is a server-side error, not a bad request. The Node.js code crashes. What does it do, what does it return? Is there a log file you can check? Try using a debugging proxy like Fiddler to see what's actually sent and received from the server.

Comment: If you search for any JSON validator and try `{"test" : 123}` you'll see it's a valid JSON string

Comment: I know that msg is valid JSON. What I was saying is that somewhere between being buffered/encoded and segmented it is no longer valid. I can send pretty much any string to the Node server unless it has double-quotes in it. I was just wondering if anyone has already encountered this.

Comment: My code is based upon a javascript program and it looks like the javascript program is "double-escaping". It's sending this: ["{\"method\":\"join\",\"data\":{\"room\":\"thing\"}}"] So I guess I need to escape all quotes and double escape any quotes that are already escaped to keep the server from having a problem.